# Why are LCM members missing from Get-DscLocalConfigurationManager result?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have two different Windows Server 2012 R2 machines (built at different times) and I want to check the LCM state in my PS script.

One server returns the [LCMState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/dsc_lcmstate) from [Get-DscLocalConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psdesiredstateconfiguration/get-dsclocalconfigurationmanager?view=powershell-4.0), the other doesn't return the LCMState or any other LCM members.

Is this due to an older version of the WMF?

I had a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/627386/what-version-of-windows-management-framework-is-installed but both servers report the same PSVersion.

On the new working server:

```
PS C:\> Get-DscLocalConfigurationManager

ActionAfterReboot              : ContinueConfiguration
AllowModuleOverwrite           : False
CertificateID                  :
ConfigurationID                :
ConfigurationMode              : ApplyAndMonitor
ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins : 15
Credential                     :
DebugMode                      : {NONE}
DownloadManagerCustomData      :
DownloadManagerName            :
LCMCompatibleVersions          : {1.0}
LCMState                       : Idle
LCMVersion                     : 1.0
RebootNodeIfNeeded             : False
RefreshFrequencyMins           : 30
RefreshMode                    : PUSH
PSComputerName                 :

PS C:\> (get-module PSDesiredStateConfiguration).Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      0      -1     -1

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.18728
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

On the older server the LCM members are not present:

```
PS C:\> Get-DscLocalConfigurationManager


AllowModuleOverwrite           : False
CertificateID                  :
ConfigurationID                :
ConfigurationMode              : ApplyAndMonitor
ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins : 30
Credential                     :
DownloadManagerCustomData      :
DownloadManagerName            :
RebootNodeIfNeeded             : False
RefreshFrequencyMins           : 15
RefreshMode                    : PUSH
PSComputerName                 :

PS C:\> (Get-Module PSDesiredStateConfiguration).Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      0      -1     -1

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34003
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16394
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

How do I obtain the LCM state on the older server?

Answer (score 0):

You have a different build on the first system (6.3.9600.18728). WMF 4.0 had a November 2014 update where some of these were introduced. So, the second system is missing [KB3000850](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3000850/november-2014-update-rollup-for-windows-rt-8-1--windows-8-1--and-windo)

Comment: I followed the link you provided to KB3000850 and tried to download the standalone update package for Win Server 2012 R2. It lets me download the msu files but these appear to only work for Win8.1.

So I get the message "The update is not applicable to your computer" and it can't install.